# Error when running php scripts on cPanel

Tags: php, cpanel

I've uploaded my site files to *../public_html* directory in cPanel. PHP scripts are in *cgi-bin* folder, each has 0755 privileges set. Domain is set up.

Html, css and javascript work fine but I get Internal Server Error when I try to execute any of php scripts.

I've tried adding

```
ini_set("include_path", '/home/*%username%*/php:' . ini_get("include_path") );
```

to each php source file (as was suggested in the PHP section of cPanel). But I keep getting the same error and the adress bar shows http://*%domain-name%*/cgi-bin/*%script-name%*.php

cPanel Error log doesn't show any errors.

cPanel documentation was completely unhelpful (for a beginner like me).

What do I have to do to make the scripts run as intented?

Comment: in the same location as your php files are executed, there should be a log file or error log. Can you tell us what it says?

Comment: @Sky you mean the cgi-bin directory? There are no log files there.

Comment: Cpanel docs speak about error log for Apache. Go to Metrics -> Errors in your Cpanel (Also can use search box for "Errors"). This show latest 300 error on your site trought apache include 500 errors.

Comment: And try putting your php files in public_html folder. Not cgi-bin folder. it should work.

Comment: @abkrim As I've mention in the post, cPanel Error log doesn't show any errors

Comment: @Sky Yay, putting them in public_html helped!
Now I need to understand what's wrong with relative paths I provided at first.

Comment: I'm glad i could help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with relative paths in html files. For some reason they were interpreted differently than on Windows with XAMPP.

I had to write all paths to php scripts starting with **/** (as relative to the home directory not the html file). And in php scripts I had to write paths to resources as relative to the php file. (Thanks @Sky for pointing me in the right direction.)

This is all very confusing and getting it right involved lots of tweaking.